# Groovy script from Jenkins Job to populate data as combo box from oracle DB is taking lot of time

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am using Groovy script to pull the data from oracle DB from Jenkins Job/Combo Box. It is taking lot of time to pull the data.

How to improve the performance?

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
Properties properties = new Properties()
File propertiesFile = new File('/opt/groovy/db.properties')
propertiesFile.withInputStream {
properties.load(it)
}
def Param = []
def arg = []
args.each{ arg.push(it)}
def dbUrl = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@' + properties.dbServer + ':52000/' + 
properties.dbSchema
sql = Sql.newInstance( dbUrl, properties.dbUser, properties.dbPassword, 
properties.dbDriver )

 switch (arg[0]) {
     case { it == 'APP' }:
        Param.push('Select')
        query = "SELECT DISTINCT APP FROM INV ORDER BY APP"
        sql.eachRow(query) { row ->
                Param.push(row[0])
        }
        def App_array_final = Param.collect{ '"' + it + '"'}
        print App_array_final
        break;
```

Comment: code could be simplified,however the it is ok. i guess problem in query itself. if the table `INV` is large then applying `DISTINCT` could be a long operation. validate your query in other tools.

Comment: Have you checked what consumes the time? If it's the query, check if APP column is indexed.